# Унарный минус из спецификации ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, runtime, ecmascript

Документ находится по ссылке https://tc39.es/ecma262/

Имеем запись вида:

```
UnaryExpression : - UnaryExpression
1. Let expr be ? Evaluation of UnaryExpression.
2. Let oldValue be ? ToNumeric(? GetValue(expr)).
3. If oldValue is a Number, then
  a. Return Number::unaryMinus(oldValue).
4. Else,
  a. Assert: oldValue is a BigInt.
  b. Return BigInt::unaryMinus(oldValue).
```

Интерес представляет абстрактная операция `GetValue`:

```
If V is not a Reference Record, return V.
2. If IsUnresolvableReference(V) is true, throw a ReferenceError exception.
3. If IsPropertyReference(V) is true, then
  a. Let baseObj be ? ToObject(V.[[Base]]).
  b. If IsPrivateReference(V) is true, then
    i. Return ? PrivateGet(baseObj, V.[[ReferencedName]]).
  c. Return ? baseObj.[[Get]](V.[[ReferencedName]], GetThisValue(V)).
4. Else,
  a. Let base be V.[[Base]].
  b. Assert: base is an Environment Record.
  c. Return ? base.GetBindingValue(V.[[ReferencedName]], V.[[Strict]])
```

Попробуем применить унарный минус к `null`:

```
-null
GetValue(null) = null // is not a Reference Record
ToNumeric(null) = +0
Number::unaryMinus(+0) = -0
```

Получаем корректный результат.

Сделаем запись в переменную и передадим `Reference Record` с `[[Base]] = null`:

```
const V = null
GetValue(V)
  if IsPropertyReference(V) = true
    Let baseObj be ? ToObject(V.[[Base]]) // ???
```

Почему на этапе `ToObject` не вызывается ошибка TypeError из-за типа Null?

Answer (score 0):

`[[Base]]` в нашем случае будет не `null`, а `EnvironmentRecord`, другими словами окружение, где объявлена переменная. Отсюда на этапе `ToObject` не вызывается ошибка.